# How to use global JS variables with Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel Mix and I have an issue with the global variables.

In the app.js file I have the following:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

var iniciateUserChoiceBool = false;

$(function() {
   require('./functions');
   require('./tabs');
});
```

The variable in question `iniciateUserChoiceBool` I am using in functions.js and in tabs.js and I need it to be the same variable. But every time I am getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: iniciateUserChoiceBool is not defined
```

If I put the variable in the different files in functions.js and in tabs.js the error is gone, but functionality changes as the variables are not the same and the `if` statement differs. How can I use global variables with Laravel mix?

I also tested it like this, still getting an error.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

$(function() {
   var iniciateUserChoiceBool = false;

   require('./functions');
   require('./tabs');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it to the `window` object:

```
window.iniciateUserChoiceBool = false;
```

This will still allow you to use just `iniciateUserChoiceBool` (without `window`) later down the line.

Comment: @Don40 Glad I could help!